# Sas Viya Deployment

Tags: sas, ansible

I am installing sas viya on linux , i have created a playbook using Ansible , edited both the file i.e. vars.yml and inventory.ini. Now when I try to test before deployment using command "ansible-playbook system-assessment.yml".
This throughs an error, mentioned in error section:

I have tried to edit var.yml and inventory.ini as per the guide from sas.

fatal: [deployTarget]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "At least one pre-flight check failed on deployTarget: Could not connect to host(s): 41.41.41.41, sas_visual_analytics."}

Comment: Anything that results in `Could not connect to host(s): 41.41.41.41`. Check you ssh keys/credentials. Is SSH enabled on that server? Does that IP really exists (proabably not)?

Comment: @Augusto ssh is enabled on the server and we can login using ssh. but at the time of deployment, we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you get the assessment playbook to work?

You can always run the playbook with extra logging to see what is happening.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini system-assessment.yml -vvvv
```